# How to tell SQLAlchemy once that I want InnoDB for the entire database?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, innodb, flask-sqlalchemy

I am managing a MySQL database with (Flask-)SQLAlchemy and I want to explicitly use `mysql_engine = InnoDB` for all tables. Is there a way to tell the database connection once that I want this, so I don't have to repeat it for every individual table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use declarative extension? If so, you can set default `__table_args__` with simple metaclass (stolen from [here](https://github.com/SmartTeleMax/iktomi/blob/master/iktomi/db/sqla/declarative.py#L66-L118)):

```
def TableArgsMeta(table_args):

    class _TableArgsMeta(declarative.DeclarativeMeta):

        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
            if (    # Do not extend base class
                    '_decl_class_registry' not in cls.__dict__ and 
                    # Missing __tablename_ or equal to None means single table
                    # inheritance — no table for it (columns go to table of
                    # base class)
                    cls.__dict__.get('__tablename__') and
                    # Abstract class — no table for it (columns go to table[s]
                    # of subclass[es]
                    not cls.__dict__.get('__abstract__', False)):
                ta = getattr(cls, '__table_args__', {})
                if isinstance(ta, dict):
                    ta = dict(table_args, **ta)
                    cls.__table_args__ = ta
                else:
                    assert isinstance(ta, tuple)
                    if ta and isinstance(ta[-1], dict):
                        tad = dict(table_args, **ta[-1])
                        ta = ta[:-1]
                    else:
                        tad = dict(table_args)
                    cls.__table_args__ = ta + (tad,)
            super(_TableArgsMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict_)

    return _TableArgsMeta
```

The usage:

```
Base = declarative_base(
            name='Base',
            metaclass=TableArgsMeta({'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}))
```

Comment: Yes, I use declarative. This looks like a good solution. If I define custom `__table_args__` for one of the models, do I still need to re-specify the `mysql_engine` or will it combine the dictionaries?

Comment: @Julian This code combines data from metaclass with what you specified in concrete mapped class. No need to re-specify it.

Comment: Great, thank you. I will test this solution upcoming Wednesday.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it does not work out of the box. When I use `Base` as indicated, I get the following exception when trying to create the tables from scratch using `create_all`: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'survey_subject.survey_id' could not find table 'survey' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`. This does not happen when I use a plain `declarative_base`.

Comment: @Julian Could you provide full traceback and a minimal example to reproduce it? Link to some pastebin service would be ok.

Comment: I will, but it might take a while. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/jgonggrijp/8db3fcef1a777caa3f65 for a backtrace and reduced demonstration.

Comment: @Julian I see the same exception when passing `_BoundDeclarativeMeta` as `metaclass` parameter instead of expression with `TableArgsMeta`. So the problem doesn't seem to be related to `TableArgsMeta`.

Comment: I managed to make it work (or at least to make the error disappear in the reduced testcase) by inheriting from `fsqla.SQLAlchemy` and overriding `fsqla.SQLAlchemy.make_declarative_base` with the code that I previously used to define `Base` in isolation. Obviously your code was not to blame, thanks for the help and your answer is hereby accepted.